# JS regular expression multi-line

Tags: javascript, regex

This one seems like it has a very simple answer, yet I can't find it anywhere. I have a regular expression that is quite large, how do I put in some line breaks in the expression itself so I don't have to keep scrolling horizontally through the code to see it all?

I don't normally use word-wrap, and the IDE I'm using doesn't even offer it anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317049/how-to-split-a-long-regular-expression-into-multiple-lines-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

A line break in a string would normally be a \ at the end of the line :

```
var mystring "my string \
is on more \
than one line";

var re = new RegExp(mystring, "gim");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RegExp` and `.join()` to convert and concat a string.

```
var myRegExp = RegExp(['/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+'
              ,'@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+'
              ,'\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/'].join(''));
```

The answer has been linked to here as well.

[How to split a long regular expression into multiple lines in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317049/how-to-split-a-long-regular-expression-into-multiple-lines-in-javascript)