# How to write big regexp in multiple lines javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a long long regexp, like this (it's example):

```
/111|112|113|...|998|999/
```

How can I make it multiline to edit it with ease? Something like that:

```
/
111
|112
|113
...
|998
|999
/
```

Comment: The question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317049/how-to-split-a-long-regular-expression-into-multiple-lines-in-javascript

Comment: If this is really your regex then why not simply `[1-9]{3}` ?

Comment: @Andreas it's example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create regexp using constructor:

```
new RegExp('/'
+ '111'
+ '|112'
+ '|113'
+ '...'
+ '|998'
+ '|999'
+ '/');
```

From ES6 you can also use `backticks` to write multiline strings:

```
new RegExp(`/
111
|112
|113
...
|998
|999
/`);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have looked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "/111|112|113|...|998|999/";
var splitArr = str.split("|");

function divide(){
   var s= "";       
   for(var i=0;i<splitArr.length;i++){
    var item = splitArr[i] + "\n";
    s +=  item;
   }
    return s
}

console.log(divide());
```