# One-line email regex works but multi-line version doesn't

Tags: javascript, regex

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) regex for email. I tried to turn it into a multi-line version. But after I do it it stops working:

```
const emailOne = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

const email = RegExp(
  /* eslint-disable */
  '^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|' +
  '(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|' +
  '(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$'
  /* eslint-enable */
)

emailOne.test('abc@gmail.com')

emailTwo.test('abc@gmail.com')
```

`emailOne` returns `true`. `emailTwo` returns `false`. Why could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

I realized that `RegExp` modifies the original regex (breaking it):

```
// regex created by RegExp
/^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

// emailOne
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Comment: @Pang Fixed the answer.

Comment: "One-line email regex works"  No it doesn't.  Your regex excludes a ton of perfectly valid e-mail addresses.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/362536

Comment: Here is a previous question asking about the same issue with what appears to be the same regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317049/how-to-split-a-long-regular-expression-into-multiple-lines-in-javascript The accepted answer should do what you need.

Comment: @Brad It's the first Google result that popped up. I included the link.

Comment: @alex The safest way to validate an email address is to send an email that requests a user action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first regex is specified with regex.  Your second one is specified with strings, and you neglected to escape the backslashes with another backslash. `\\`