# Clean way to keep original variable and destructure at the same time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-next, ecmascript-2016

Is there a cleaner way to do this (with anything that is at least an ES draft and has a babel plugin, i.e., ES6, ES7, etc.):

```
const { a, b } = result = doSomething();
```

Where I want to keep the overall result as one singular object, but also destructure it at the same time. It technically works, but `result` is implicitly declared (with an implicit `var`), while I'd really like it to also be a const.

I'm currently doing this:

```
const result = doSomething();
const { a, b } = result;
```

Which again works, but it's slightly on the verbose side, since I need to repeat this pattern dozens of times.

I'd ideally want something along the lines of:

```
const { a, b } = const result = doSomething();
```

But that is obviously an invalid syntax.

Comment: The first snippet doesn't declare `var` implicitly. It's undeclared variable that will result in global variable in loose mode and fail in strict mode.

Comment: Using two statements is the clean and proper way. And it's not overly verbose either. I rather am concerned why you say that you have to repeat this dozens of times?

Comment: In this particular case, it's because there are a series of basically reducer functions. Each function is independent, but follows a similar pattern. Each function is supposed to update the original input, and then pass it back out so the next reducer in the chain can run it. They end like this: `return Object.assign(result, { a: a + 5 })` where I spit out everything plus the update.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One possible way:

```
const result = doSomething(), 
    { a, b } = result;
```

You still have to duplicate the name, though. `const` token isn't quite right-handy. )

Comment: That is a bit cleaner, and probably about the closest I'll be able to get with the current standard. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

### Idea 1

Create this helper function:

```
function use(input, callback) {
    callback(input, input);
}
```

and use it like:

```
use(doSomething(), (result, {a, b}) => {
    // Do something with result as a whole, or a and b as destructured properties.
});
```

For example:

```
use ({a: "Hello", b: "World", c: "!"}, (result, {a, b}) => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
});

// generates
// {a: "Hello", b: "World", c: "!"}
// Hello
// World
```

> They're not `const`, but they're scoped, for better or worse!

---

### Idea 2

Combine `array` and `object` deconstruction. Create this helper function:

```
const dup = input => [input, input];
```

And then deconstruct away like so:

```
const [result, {a, b}] = dup(doSomething());
```

> Now, your `result`, `a`, and `b` are all `const`s.

Answer (score 5):

In @raina77ow's answer they lament **`const`**`token isn't quite right-handy`; but if you use a colon (and repeat the keyword) instead of a comma, there's your answer.
But you already mentioned `const result = doSomething(); const {a, b} = result;` in your question, I dont see how it's any worse, and it works.

But from that, one thing you can see is that `let something = x; let another = y;` is the same as `let [something, another] = [x, y];`.
**Thus a really elegant solution is actually simply**:

```
const [result, {a, b}] = [,,].fill(doSomething());
```

You need the extra `,` as it is [trailing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas)

---

---

In addition to this *(to make it it's own answer instead of only comment-worthy)*, this duplicating can also be done *inside* the destructuring syntaxt (which is why I came across this question).
Say `b` within `result` itself had a `c`; you want to destructure that, *but also keep the reference to `b`*.

```
//The above might lead you to believe you need to do this:
const result = doSomething(); const {a, b} = result; const {c} = b;
//or this
const [result, {a, b}, {b:{c}}] = [,,,].fill(doSomething());
```

But you can actually just

```
const [result, {a, b, b:{c}}] = [,,].fill(doSomething());
```

Now you have `result`, `a`, `b`, & `c`, even though a & b were in result, and c was in b.
This is especially handy if you dont actually need `result`, it looks like `fill()` is only required for the root object:
`const {a, b, b:{c}} = doSomething();`

This mightn't seem to work for arrays, since the *position* in the syntax *is the key*

```
const [result, [a, b, /*oops, I'm referencing index 2 now*/]] = [,,].fill(doArrayThing());
```

However, arrays *are objects*, so you can just use indices as keys and dupe an index reference:

```
const [result, {0:a, 1:b, 1:{c}}] = [,,].fill(doArrayThing());
```

This also means you can destructure array-likes, whereas normally it complains about the object not being iterable, and you can skip indices by just using a higher key instead of the array's syntax where you'll have to write empty commas.
And perhaps the best of all, `{0:a, 1:b, ...c}` still works as `[a, b, ...c]` would, since `Object.keys()` for an array pulls its indices (but the resulting `c` will not have a `.length`).

---

---

But I'm not content with that, and I really liked where @Arash was going with idea #2, but it wasn't generic enough to help with de-duping the `b` in the example above, and it dupes the `const` lines.

So...I wrote my own :| (ctrl+F for `goodluck`)
You use the same normal syntax, with some exceptions:

- your destructure is written in a template literal, with the input object appearing as an interpolation
  eg `[,,] = input` becomes `` `[,,] = ${input}` ``
- The equals is actually optional
- you never rename the outputs *within the destruction*
  eg `[a, b, ...c] = input` becomes `` `[, , ...] ${input}` ``
- the output of this template ran against `μ` (you can name it whatever) is an array of the elements you specified in order
  eg `const {a:A, b:B} = input;` becomes `` const [A,B] = μ`{a, b} ${input}`; ``
  NB how the rename comes at the output. And even if the input is an object, the output is always a flat array.
- you can skip elements in an iterator using a number instead of repeated commas
  eg `const [a, , , d] = input;` is `` const [a,d] = μ`[ , 2, ]`; ``
- **and finally, the whole point of this; when going into an object, preceding it with a colon saves it to the output**

eg

```
const [result, {a, b, b:{c}}] = [,,].fill(doSomething());
```

becomes

```
const [result, a, b] = μ`:{a, b::{c}} ${doSomething()}`;
```

---

So, other than the above, the pros:

- I'm not running eval at all, but actually parsing and applying logic to your input,
  as such I can give you **way** better error messages at *runtime*.

Eg ES6 doesnt even bother with this one:

```
_ = {a:7, get b() {throw 'hi'}};
console.warn('ES6');
out(() => {
    const {a, b} = _;
    return [a, b];
});
console.warn('hashbrown');
out(() => {
    const {a,b} = μ`{a,...} ${_}`;
    return [a, b];
});
```

[image]

Eg2 Here ES6 says `_` was the culprit. Not only do I correctly say it was `1` at fault, but I tell you where in the destructure it happened:

```
_ = [1];
console.warn('ES6');
out(() => {
    const [[a]] = _;
    return [a];
});
console.warn('hashbrown');
out(() => {
    const [a] = μ`[[]] ${_}`;
    return [a];
});
```

[image]

- super handy if you need to skip large arrays or are keeping a lot of inner variables

Eg

```
const [[a,,,,,,,,,j], [[aa, ab], [ba]]] = [,,].fill(_);
const [a, aa, ab, ba, j] = μ`[:[ , ], [ ], 7, ] ${_}`;
```

---

Okay, what's the catch? The cons:

- well even that last pro, the destruction syntax with all the names missing can be hard to read. Really we need this syntax *in the language*, so the names are inside it instead of the `const [` happening outside of it.
- compilers dont know what to do with this, syntax errors are runtime (whereas you'd be told earlier natively with ES6), IDE's probably wont be able to tell whats getting spat out (and I'm refusing to write a properly done templated `.d.ts` for it) if you're using some sort of typechecking
- and as alluded to before you get slightly worse *compile time* errors for your syntax. I just tell you that something wasn't right, not what.
  But, to be fair, I still tell you where you went wrong, if you have multiple rest operators, I dont think ES6 is much help

Eg

```
_ = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.warn('ES6');
out(() => {
    eval(`const [a, ...betwixt, b] = _`);
    return [a, betwixt, b];
});
console.warn('hashbrown');
out(() => {
    const [a, betwixt, b] = μ`[, ..., ] ${_}`;
    return [a, betwixt, b];
});
```

[image]

- it's really only worth it if you're dealing with arrays, or you're renaming all the outputs anyway, because otherwise you're left specifying the name twice. This would be fixed along with point 1 if `:{` `:[` and `[2` were adopted into the language, you wouldn't need to respecify outside in your `const [`
- how I wrote it it honestly probably only runs in Chrome since [firefox still doesn't have named capture groups](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362154). I was diligent in writing the [regex] parser to make all unused groups non-capturing, so if you're keen, it wouldn't be hard to make it FF-compatible

---

[So where's the code?

You're keen.

Goodluck.](https://jsfiddle.net/anmb03jf/)

```
window.μ = (() => {
    //build regexes without worrying about
    // - double-backslashing
    // - adding whitespace for readability
    // - adding in comments
    let clean = (piece) => (piece
        .replace(/(?<=^|\n)(?<line>(?:[^\/\\]|\/[^*\/]|\\.)*)\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(\*\/|)/g, '$<line>')
        .replace(/(?<=^|\n)(?<line>(?:[^\/\\]|\/[^\/]|\\.)*)\/\/[^\n]*/g, '$<line>')
        .replace(/\n\s*/g, '')
    );
    let regex = ({raw}, ...interpolations) => (
        new RegExp(interpolations.reduce(
            (regex, insert, index) => (regex + insert + clean(raw[index + 1])),
            clean(raw[0])
        ))
    );

    let start = {
        parse : regex`^\s*(?:
            //the end of the string
            //I permit the equal sign or just declaring the input after the destructure definition without one
            (?<done>=?\s*)
            |
            //save self to output?
            (?<read>(?<save>:\s*|))
            //opening either object or array
            (?<next>(?<open>[{[]).*)
        )$`
    };
    let object = {
        parse : regex`^\s*
            (?<read>
                //closing the object
                (?<close>\})|

                //starting from open or comma you can...
                (?:[,{]\s*)(?:
                    //have a rest operator
                    (?<rest>\.\.\.)
                    |
                    //have a property key
                    (?<key>
                        //a non-negative integer
                        \b\d+\b
                        |
                        //any unencapsulated string of the following
                        \b[A-Za-z$_][\w$]*\b
                        |
                        //a quoted string
                        (?<quoted>"|')(?:
                            //that contains any non-escape, non-quote character
                            (?!\k<quoted>|\\).
                            |
                            //or any escape sequence
                            (?:\\.)
                        //finished by the quote
                        )*\k<quoted>
                    )
                    //after a property key, we can go inside
                    \s*(?<inside>:|)
                )
            )
            (?<next>(?:
                //after closing we expect either
                // - the parent's comma/close,
                // - or the end of the string
                (?<=\})\s*(?:[,}\]=]|$)
                |
                //after the rest operator we expect the close
                (?<=\.)\s*\}
                |
                //after diving into a key we expect that object to open
                (?<=:)\s*[{[:]
                |
                //otherwise we saw only a key, we now expect a comma or close
                (?<=[^:\.}])\s*[,}]
            ).*)
        $`,
        //for object, pull all keys we havent used
        rest : (obj, keys) => (
            Object.keys(obj)
                .filter((key) => (!keys[key]))
                .reduce((output, key) => {
                    output[key] = obj[key];
                    return output;
                }, {})
        )
    };
    let array = {
        parse : regex`^\s*
            (?<read>
                //closing the array
                (?<close>\])
                |
                //starting from open or comma you can...
                (?:[,[]\s*)(?:
                    //have a rest operator
                    (?<rest>\.\.\.)
                    |
                    //skip some items using a positive integer
                    (?<skip>\b[1-9]\d*\b)
                    |
                    //or just consume an item
                    (?=[^.\d])
                )
            )
            (?<next>(?:
                //after closing we expect either
                // - the parent's comma/close,
                // - or the end of the string
                (?<=\])\s*(?:[,}\]=]|$)
                |
                //after the rest operator we expect the close
                (?<=\.)\s*\]
                |
                //after a skip we expect a comma
                (?<=\d)\s*,
                |
                //going into an object
                (?<=[,[])\s*(?<inside>[:{[])
                |
                //if we just opened we expect to consume or consume one and close
                (?<=\[)\s*[,\]]
                |
                //otherwise we're just consuming an item, we expect a comma or close
                (?<=[,[])\s*[,\]]
            ).*)
        $`,
        //for 'array', juice the iterator
        rest : (obj, keys) => (Array.from(keys))
    };

    let destructure = ({next, input, used}) => {
//for exception handling
let phrase = '';
let debugging = () => {
    let tmp = type;
    switch (tmp) {
    case object: tmp = 'object'; break;
    case array : tmp = 'array'; break;
    case start : tmp = 'start'; break;
    }
    console.warn(
        `${tmp}\t%c${phrase}%c\u2771%c${next}`,
        'font-family:"Lucida Console";',
        'font-family:"Lucida Console";background:yellow;color:black;',
        'font-family:"Lucida Console";',
//input, used
    );
};
debugging = null;
        //this algorithm used to be recursive and beautiful, I swear,
        //but I unwrapped it into the following monsterous (but efficient) loop.
        //
        //Lots of array destructuring and it was really easy to follow the different parse paths,
        //now it's using much more efficient `[].pop()`ing.
        //
        //One thing that did get much nicer with this change was the error handling.
        //having the catch() rethrow and add snippets to the string as it bubbled back out was...gross, really
        let read, quoted, key, save, open, inside, close, done, rest, type, keys, parents, stack, obj, skip;
try {
        let output = [];
        while (
            //this is the input object and any in the stack prior
            [obj, ...parents] = input,
            //this is the map of used keys used for the rest operator
            [keys, ...stack] = used,
            //assess the type from how we are storing the used 'keys'
            type = (!keys) ? start : (typeof keys.next == 'function') ? array : object,
phrase += (read || ''),
read = '',
debugging && debugging(),
            //parse the phrase, deliberately dont check if it doesnt match; this way it will throw
            {read, quoted, next, key, save, open, inside, close, done, rest, skip} = next.match(type.parse).groups,
            done == null
        ) {
            if (open) {
                //THIS IS THE EXTRA FUNCTIONALITY
                if (save)
                    output.push(obj);
                switch (open) {
                case '{':
                    used = [{}, ...stack];
                    break;
                case '[':
                    used = [obj[Symbol.iterator](), ...stack];
                    input = [null, ...parents];
                    break;
                default:
                    throw open;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (close) {
                used = stack;
                input = parents;
                continue;
            }
            //THIS IS THE EXTRA FUNCTIONALITY
            if (skip) {
                for (skip = parseInt(skip); skip-- > 0; keys.next());
                continue;
            }

            //rest operator
            if (rest) {
                obj = type.rest(obj, keys);
                //anticipate an immediate close
                input = [null, ...parents];
            }
            //fetch the named item
            else if (key) {
                if (quoted) {
                    key = JSON.parse(key);
                }
                keys[key] = true;
                obj = obj[key];
            }
            //fetch the next item
            else
                obj = keys.next().value;

            //dive into the named object or append it to the output
            if (inside) {
                input = [obj, ...input];
                used = [null, ...used];
            }
            else
                output.push(obj);
        }
        return output;
}
catch (e) {
    console.error('%c\u26A0 %cError destructuring', 'color:yellow;', '', ...input);
    console.error(
        `%c\u26A0 %c${phrase}%c${read || '\u2771'}%c${next || ''}`,
        'color:yellow;',
        'font-family:"Lucida Console";',
        'font-family:"Lucida Console";background:red;color:white;',
        'font-family:"Lucida Console";'
    );
    throw e;
}
return null;
    };
    //just to rearrange the inputs from template literal tags to what destructure() expects.
    //I used to have the function exposed directly but once I started supporting
    //iterators and spread I had multiple stacks to maintain and it got messy.
    //Now that it's wrapped it runs iteratively instead of recursively.
    return ({raw:[next]}, ...input) => (destructure({next, input, used:[]}));
})();
```

The demo's tests:

```
let out = (func) => {
    try {
        console.log(...func().map((arg) => (JSON.stringify(arg))));
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};
let _;

//THE FOLLOWING WORK (AND ARE MEANT TO)
_ = {a:{aa:7}, b:8};
out(() => {
    const [input,{a,a:{aa},b}] = [,,].fill(_);
    return [input, a, b, aa];
});
out(() => {
    const [input,a,aa,b] = μ`:{a::{aa},b}=${_}`;
    return [input, a, b, aa];
});

_ = [[65, -4], 100, [3, 5]];
out(() => {
    //const [[aa, ab], , c] = input; const [ca, cb] = c;
    const {0:{0:aa, 1:ab}, 2:c, 2:{0:ca, 1:cb}} = _;
    return [aa, ab, c, ca, cb];
});
out(() => {
    const [aa,ab,c,ca,cb] = μ`{0:{0,1}, 2::{0,1}}=${_}`;
    return [aa, ab, c, ca, cb];
});

_ = {a:{aa:7, ab:[7.5, 7.6, 7.7], 'a c"\'':7.8}, b:8};
out(() => {
    const [input,{a,a:{aa,ab,ab:{0:aba, ...abb},"a c\"'":ac},b,def='hi'}] = [,,].fill(_);
    return [input, a, aa, ab, aba, abb, ac, b, def];
});
out(() => {
    const [input,a,aa,ab,aba,abb,ac,b,def='hi'] = μ`:{a::{aa,ab::{0, ...},"a c\"'"},b}=${_}`;
    return [input, a, aa, ab, aba, abb, ac, b, def];
});

_ = [{aa:7, ab:[7.5, {abba:7.6}, 7.7], 'a c"\'':7.8}, 8];
out(() => {
    const [input,[{aa,ab,ab:[aba,{abba},...abc],"a c\"'":ac}],[a,b,def='hi']] = [,,,].fill(_);
    return [input, a, aa, ab, aba, abba, abc, ac, b, def];
});
out(() => {
    const [input,a,aa,ab,aba,abba,abc,ac,b,def='hi'] = μ`:[:{aa,ab::[,{abba},...],"a c\"'"},]=${_}`;
    return [input, a, aa, ab, aba, abba, abc, ac, b, def];
});

_ = [[-1,-2],[-3,-4],4,5,6,7,8,9,0,10];
out(() => {
    const [[a,,,,,,,,,j], [[aa, ab], [ba]]] = [,,].fill(_);
    return [a, aa, ab, ba, j];
});
out(() => {
    const [a, aa, ab, ba, j] = μ`[:[ , ], [ ], 7, ] ${_}`;
    return [a, aa, ab, ba, j];
});


//THE FOLLOWING FAIL (AND ARE MEANT TO)

_ = [1];
console.warn('ES6');
out(() => {
    const [[a]] = _;
    return [a];
});
console.warn('hashbrown');
out(() => {
    const [a] = μ`[[]] ${_}`;
    return [a];
});


_ = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.warn('ES6');
out(() => {
    eval(`const [a, ...betwixt, b] = _`);
    return [a, betwixt, b];
});
console.warn('hashbrown');
out(() => {
    const [a, betwixt, b] = μ`[, ..., ] ${_}`;
    return [a, betwixt, b];
});


_ = {a:7, get b() {throw 'hi'}};
console.warn('ES6');
out(() => {
    const {a, b} = _;
    return [a, b];
});
console.warn('hashbrown');
out(() => {
    const {a,b} = μ`{a,...} ${_}`;
    return [a, b];
});
```

And the output if your browser couldn't run it but you're curious (the errors are testing error outputs for native vs this thing)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Destructuring an object using a key twice is allowed. Do that a wrapper and it works well for me. The key can be `data`, `_`, or whatever you like.

This works in Javascript and Typescript.

```js
const getMealData = () => ({ breakfast: 'fried egg ', lunch: 'sushi ' })

const {
  data: mealData,
  data: { breakfast },
} = { data: getMealData() }

console.log(mealData) // { breakfast: 'fried egg ', lunch: 'sushi ' }
console.log(breakfast) // "fried egg "
```

Answer (score 0):

Went looking for a good solution and ended up working it out so thought I would throw this in with the MANY solutions in this old thread...

This returns an object with an additional field being the raw return.
The same thing works for destructuring hooks into an array.

```js
  const { a, b, func } = (x => ({ ...x, func: x }))(doSomething());
```