# How to break a line of source code in Qt QML

Tags: regex, qt, syntax, qml

I need to break a long regular expression in Qt QML source file, for example:

```
TextInput {
  ...
  validator: RegExpValidator {
    regExp: /Here goes a very long regular expression. I want to break it to multiple lines/
  }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? your link is to a java question, this question is QML.

Answer (score 0):

This is a five year old question. However, just in case someone still wonders. Based on [How to split a long regular expression into multiple lines in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317049/how-to-split-a-long-regular-expression-into-multiple-lines-in-javascript) it can be solved in multiple ways in JavaScript QML syntax, Including:

```
TextInput {
        color: "red"
        text: "44444AAAAAA"
        id: userinput
        validator: RegularExpressionValidator {
            regularExpression: new RegExp(
                                   /[0-9]+/.source
                                   +/[A-Z]+/.source
                                   )
        }
        onAccepted: {
            console.log("valid input");
            text:displayText
        }
    }
```