# Optimize long lists of fixed string alternatives in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, optimization

I have an expression for selecting times in some timezones, I mention my expression in the below:

```
/(\d+)(?:[.: ](\d\d))*\s*([aApP][.: ]?[mM][.: ]?|o'clock |o’clock)*\s*(PT|AT|PST|PDT|UTC|EST)/gm;
```

In this expression I just use `PT|AT|PST|PDT|UTC|EST` timezones, but I want to add all list based on [Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/). Should I insert all list in the expression? Is there any better solution?

Comment: There is a way! There are flags to turn off significant whitespace and then put each "atom" of the regex on a separate line, with an explanatory comment alongside (similar to how some code-golf answers are explained). I saw this once a couple years ago on someone's website, but don't have the bookmark handy. If I find it, I'll come back to post it (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: I'll add that doing this with a regex is "hard mode." You may be able to get it to work, but as you have noted, it's not especially clear. It is probably easier to chop up the original string into parts and then use simpler logic or even straightforward string matching to validate those chunks.

Comment: `|o'clock |o’clock` can be simply `|o['’]clock`. As for the timezone abbreviation list, yes you'll have to create a giant boolean expression or `[A-Z]{1,5}\b` would likely suffice.

Comment: Tom's point is (IMO) that when regex is your hammer everything looks like a thumb. Miniature, focused mini-languages/-parsers are often a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Tom Given how easy it is to verify that the `/x` flag is not supported I assumed you didn't know this question was tagged Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_regexp_flag. You could however build a regex string and concatenate however you wish per JS's string concatenation rules.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks, Can I use a string to store the list of all timezones and then put it in the expression?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus As I said, I saw someone do this, _once_. I don't know how they did it. If I had that info, I would have posted an answer. It seems like you are trying to discourage me from even doing the research, merely because some specific mechanism you've alluded to from some other language is known to not work in JS.

Comment: @HanieAsemi Certainly, you'll need to use the [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with a string constructor like this `let timezones = 'PT|AT|PST|PDT|UTC|EST|etc...'; let re = new RegExp( 'my regular expression'+timemzones, 'gm' );`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've checked this but using `RegExp` changes my expression for example `\` will be deleted.

Comment: Your regex's `'` should be `\'` since we're dealing with strings instead of regex literals now. You need to follow Javascript's string escape rules.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @HanieAsemi This isn't what I was referring to earlier, but you might find it appealing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60027277/814463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a regex trie out of the words at the MyRegexTester.com site:

1. Grab the list of all the time zones from the site you trust as a list of words each on its own line
2. Go to https://www.myregextester.com/index.php
3. Select `WORDLIST` from the dropdown box right below *HIGHLIGHT MATCHES* check box
   [image]
4. Paste the time zone string list and click [image]

You will get something like

```js
^(?:A(?:C(?:WS|[DS])?T|DT|E[DS]?T|FT|K[DS]T|LMT|M[S]?T|NAS?T|QTT|RT|ST|W[DS]T|Z(?:OS|[OS])?T|oE|T)|B(?:RS|[NORST])T|C(?:AS|ES|H(?:A[DS]|OS|[OU])|ID?S|LS|hS|[ACDEKLOSVX])?T|D(?:AV|DU)T|E(?:ASS?|ES|GS|[ACDEGS])?T|F(?:JS|KS|[EJKN])T|G(?:A[LM]|IL|[EFMSY])T|H(?:OVS?|[DKS])T|I(?:R(?:KS|[DKS])|[CDOS])T|JST|K(?:OS|RAS?|UY|[GS])T|L(?:H[DS]|IN)T|M(?:A(?:GS|[GRW])T|DT|HT|MT|S[DKT]|UT|VT|YT|T)|N(?:FD|OVS?|Z[DS]|[CDFPRSU])T|O(?:MSS?|RA)T|P(?:ETS?|HO|M[DS]|ON|YS|[DEGHKSWY])?T|QYZT|R(?:OT|E)T|S(?:A[KMS]|RE|YO|[BCGRS])T|T(?:AH|OS|[FJKLMORV])T|U(?:LAS?T|TC|YS?T|ZT)|V(?:LAS?|OS|[EU])T|W(?:A(?:RS|[KS])?T|ES?T|FT|GS?T|I(?:TA|[BT])|ST|T)|Y(?:A(?:KS|[KP])|EKS?)T|[ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])$
```

This codes [244 time zones](https://regex101.com/r/Yqy1Uw/1).

Now, it is time to build the final regex. Take out the anchors from the above, you do not need the `^` and `$` when the pattern is used in the middle of another regex.

```js
const tz = "(?:A(?:C(?:WS|[DS])?T|DT|E[DS]?T|FT|K[DS]T|LMT|M[S]?T|NAS?T|QTT|RT|ST|W[DS]T|Z(?:OS|[OS])?T|oE|T)|B(?:RS|[NORST])T|C(?:AS|ES|H(?:A[DS]|OS|[OU])|ID?S|LS|hS|[ACDEKLOSVX])?T|D(?:AV|DU)T|E(?:ASS?|ES|GS|[ACDEGS])?T|F(?:JS|KS|[EJKN])T|G(?:A[LM]|IL|[EFMSY])T|H(?:OVS?|[DKS])T|I(?:R(?:KS|[DKS])|[CDOS])T|JST|K(?:OS|RAS?|UY|[GS])T|L(?:H[DS]|IN)T|M(?:A(?:GS|[GRW])T|DT|HT|MT|S[DKT]|UT|VT|YT|T)|N(?:FD|OVS?|Z[DS]|[CDFPRSU])T|O(?:MSS?|RA)T|P(?:ETS?|HO|M[DS]|ON|YS|[DEGHKSWY])?T|QYZT|R(?:OT|E)T|S(?:A[KMS]|RE|YO|[BCGRS])T|T(?:AH|OS|[FJKLMORV])T|U(?:LAS?T|TC|YS?T|ZT)|V(?:LAS?|OS|[EU])T|W(?:A(?:RS|[KS])?T|ES?T|FT|GS?T|I(?:TA|[BT])|ST|T)|Y(?:A(?:KS|[KP])|EKS?)T|[ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])"
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`(\d+)(?:[.: ](\d\d))*\s*([aApP][.: ]?[mM][.: ]?|o['’]clock)*\s*${tz}`, 'gm');
console.log(regex.source)
```

I am not sure the regex will work for you in the end, see [its demo online](https://regex101.com/r/Yqy1Uw/2), but now you see how you can use a collection of literal string patterns inside a regex pattern in the most optimal way.

To build regex tries dynamically inside your code, you need something like [`trie-regex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trie-regex). There are other applications that are capable of creating regex tries out of string lists.

**Below, you can generate a regex trie for your given comma or linebreak separated word list**:

```js
!function(){return function t(e,n,r){function i(s,u){if(!n[s]){if(!e[s]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!u&&c)return c(s,!0);if(o)return o(s,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+s+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var a=n[s]={exports:{}};e[s][0].call(a.exports,function(t){return i(e[s][1][t]||t)},a,a.exports,t,e,n,r)}return n[s].exports}for(var o="function"==typeof require&&require,s=0;s<r.length;s++)i(r[s]);return i}}()({1:[function(t,e,n){(function(t){(function(){!function(r){var i="object"==typeof n&&n,o="object"==typeof e&&e&&e.exports==i&&e,s="object"==typeof t&&t;s.global!==s&&s.window!==s||(r=s);var u={},c=u.hasOwnProperty,f=function(t,e){var n;for(n in t)c.call(t,n)&&e(n,t[n])},a=u.toString,p={'"':'\\"',"'":"\\'","\\":"\\\\","\b":"\\b","\f":"\\f","\n":"\\n","\r":"\\r","\t":"\\t"},_=/["'\\\b\f\n\r\t]/,h=/[0-9]/,l=/[ !#-&\(-\[\]-~]/,d=function(t,e){var n,r,i={escapeEverything:!1,quotes:"single",wrap:!1,es6:!1,json:!1,compact:!0,indent:"\t",__indent__:""},o=e&&e.json;o&&(i.quotes="double",i.wrap=!0),n=i,"single"!=(e=(r=e)?(f(r,function(t,e){n[t]=e}),n):n).quotes&&"double"!=e.quotes&&(e.quotes="single");var s,u,c,g="double"==e.quotes?'"':"'",y=e.compact,v=e.indent,b=y?"":"\n",j=!0;if(o&&t&&("function"==typeof(c=t.toJSON)||"[object Function]"==a.call(c))&&(t=t.toJSON()),!function(t){return"string"==typeof t||"[object String]"==a.call(t)}(t))return function(t){return"[object Array]"==a.call(t)}(t)?(u=[],e.wrap=!0,s=e.__indent__,v+=s,e.__indent__=v,function(t,e){for(var n=t.length,r=-1;++r<n;)e(t[r])}(t,function(t){j=!1,u.push((y?"":v)+d(t,e))}),j?"[]":"["+b+u.join(","+b)+b+(y?"":s)+"]"):function(t){return"[object Object]"==a.call(t)}(t)?(u=[],e.wrap=!0,s=e.__indent__,v+=s,e.__indent__=v,f(t,function(t,n){j=!1,u.push((y?"":v)+d(t,e)+":"+(y?"":" ")+d(n,e))}),j?"{}":"{"+b+u.join(","+b)+b+(y?"":s)+"}"):o?JSON.stringify(t)||"null":String(t);var w,m,x=t,q=-1,E=x.length;for(u="";++q<E;){var S=x.charAt(q);if(e.es6&&(w=x.charCodeAt(q))>=55296&&w<=56319&&E>q+1&&(m=x.charCodeAt(q+1))>=56320&&m<=57343)u+="\\u{"+(1024*(w-55296)+m-56320+65536).toString(16).toUpperCase()+"}",q++;else{if(!e.escapeEverything){if(l.test(S)){u+=S;continue}if('"'==S){u+=g==S?'\\"':S;continue}if("'"==S){u+=g==S?"\\'":S;continue}}if("\0"!=S||o||h.test(x.charAt(q+1)))if(_.test(S))u+=p[S];else{var O=S.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase(),A=O.length>2||o,N="\\"+(A?"u":"x")+("0000"+O).slice(A?-4:-2);u+=N}else u+="\\0"}}return e.wrap&&(u=g+u+g),u};d.version="0.5.0","function"==typeof define&&"object"==typeof define.amd&&define.amd?define(function(){return d}):i&&!i.nodeType?o?o.exports=d:i.jsesc=d:r.jsesc=d}(this)}).call(this)}).call(this,"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:"undefined"!=typeof window?window:{})},{}],2:[function(t,e,n){var r=t("jsesc"),i=function(){"use strict";var t=function(){return this instanceof t?(this._num_phrases_in_trie=0,this._trie={},this):new t};return t.prototype.add=function(t){if(t instanceof Array&&t.forEach(this.add,this),t=this._coerce_to_string(t),!this._is_phrase_valid(t))return this;if(this.contains(t))return this;var e=this._trie;return t.split("").forEach(function(t){t in e?e=e[t]:(e[t]={},e=e[t])},this),e.end=!0,this._num_phrases_in_trie++,this},t.prototype.toRegExp=function(){if(0!==this._num_phrases_in_trie){var t=this.toString();return new RegExp(t)}},t.prototype.toString=function(){if(0!==this._num_phrases_in_trie){var t=function(e,n){var r=Object.keys(e),i=[],o=[],s=!1;return r.forEach(function(u){var c;"end"!==u?(c=this._quotemeta(u)+t(e[u],n),(r.length>1?[].push.bind(i):[].push.bind(o))(c)):s=!0},n),n._to_regex(i,o,s)};return t(this._trie,this)}},t.prototype._to_regex=function(t,e,n){var r="";return t.length>0?1===t.length?r+=t[0]:t.every(function(t){return 1===t.length})?r+="["+t.join("")+"]":r+="(?:"+t.join("|")+")":e.length>0&&(r+=e[0]),n&&r&&(1===r.length?r+="?":r="(?:"+r+")?"),r},t.prototype.contains=function(t){if(!this._is_phrase_valid(t)&&this._num_phrases_in_trie>0)return!1;var e=this._trie;try{return t.split("").forEach(function(t){e=e[t]}),e.hasOwnProperty("end")&&!0===e.end}catch(t){}return!1},t.prototype._coerce_to_string=function(t){return"number"!=typeof t||isNaN(t)||(t=t.toString()),t},t.prototype._is_phrase_valid=function(t){return"string"==typeof t&&t.length>0},t.prototype._quotemeta=function(t){return this._is_phrase_valid(t)?t.replace(/([\t\n\f\r\\\$\(\)\*\+\-\.\?\[\]\^\{\|\}])/g,"\\$1").replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g,r):t},t}();e.exports=i},{jsesc:1}],3:[function(t,e,n){$(document).ready(function(){$("#run").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(),$("#result").html("");const n=$("#inputdata").val().match(/[^\r\n,]+/g);let r=new(t("regex-trie"));r.add(n);const i=r.toRegExp();$("#result").append("<b>"+i.source.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;")+"</b><br/>")})})},{"regex-trie":2}]},{},[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Add the comma or linebreak separated words to the text area and click <i>Generate</i>.</p>
  <textarea id="inputdata"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <button id="run">Generate</BUTTON>
  <pre><code id="result" /></pre>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot for writing a useful regex for all timezones and finally I've written the below regex, hope this helps others:

```
const tz = "(?:A(?:C(?:WS|[DS])?T|DT|E[DS]?T|FT|K[DS]T|LMT|M[S]?T|NAS?T|QTT|RT|ST|W[DS]T|Z(?:OS|[OS])?T|oE|T)|B(?:RS|[NORST])T|C(?:AS|ES|H(?:A[DS]|OS|[OU])|ID?S|LS|hS|[ACDEKLOSVX])?T|D(?:AV|DU)T|E(?:ASS?|ES|GS|[ACDEGS])?T|F(?:iS|KS|[EiKN])T|G(?:A[LM]|IL|[EFMSY])T*\\s*(?:(?:([+ -][0-9]{1,4})(?:[.:](\\d\\d)?)?)?)|H(?:OVS?|[DKS])T|I(?:R(?:KS|[DKS])|[CDOS])T|iST|K(?:OS|RAS?|UY|[GS])T|L(?:H[DS]|IN)T|M(?:A(?:GS|[GRW])T|DT|HT|MT|S[DKT]|UT|VT|YT|T)|N(?:FD|OVS?|Z[DS]|[CDFPRSU])T|O(?:MSS?|RA)T|P(?:ETS?|HO|M[DS]|ON|YS|[DEGHKSWY])?T|QYZT|R(?:OT|E)T|S(?:A[KMS]|RE|YO|[BCGRS])T|T(?:AH|OS|[FiKLMORV])T|U(?:LAS?T|TC*\\s*([+ -][0-9]{1,4}(?:[.:](\\d\\d))?)|YS?T|ZT)|V(?:LAS?|OS|[EU])T|W(?:A(?:RS|[KS])?T|ES?T|FT|GS?T|I(?:TA|[BT])|ST|T)|Y(?:A(?:KS|[KP])|EKS?)T)"
const numbers = "(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|One|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six|Seven|Eight|Nine|Ten)"
const partOfDay = "(morning|afternoon|evening)"
const timeExpression = new RegExp(String.raw `\d{1,2}(?:[.:](\d\d))*\s*([aApP][.: ]?[mM][.: ]?|o['’]clock|afternoon|\d{2})*\s* ${tz}|${numbers} ${partOfDay} ${tz}`, 'gm');
```