# How would I match `.scss`, `.sass`, `.css` but not `.ass`? (RegExp)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex: `/\.([s]?[ac]ss)$/`. The problem is, it matches `.scss`, `.sass`, `.css`, `.ass`. How would I make it not match `.ass`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also this will match `.scss`, `.sass` and `.css` only, it is very readable and self-explanatory

```
/\.(sc|sa|c)ss$/
```

Comment: Maybe even more readible would be `\.(?:s?c|sa)ss`?

Comment: This is the simplest one yet. I prefer `/\.(sc|sa|c)ss$/` over `/\.(?:s?c|sa)ss/` since the first is very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another way using alternation:

```sh
\.((?:s[ac]|c)ss)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XcnKBe/1)

Here this non-capturing group `(?:s[ac]|c)` will match `sa` or `sc` or just `c`.

Answer (score 3):

How about just

```regex
/\.(s?css|sass)$/
```

Regex doesn't need to be very complex to work. This is a lot easier to read for other programmers (*i.e. you in about 3 months*) and does the same.

Sure you can smush it more together, but why would you? Regex are complicated enough, keep 'm simple if you can :)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqjfYs/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\.(?!a)(s?[ac]ss)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/652AYf/1). *Details*:

- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!a)` -  the next char cannot be `a`
- `(s?[ac]ss)` - Group 1: an optional `s`, `a` or `c` and then `ss`
- `$` - end of string.

Another regex that can work is

```
\.(s(?:css|ass)|css)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/652AYf/5). *Details*:

- `\.` - a dot
- `(s(?:css|ass)|css)` - `s` and then `css` or `ass` or `css`
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: if you have a dynamic, user-defined list of such fixed strings to match after a `.` at the end of string, you can build these regexes automatically using the code at the bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68275882/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You could just list the ones you want to match:

```
let rx = /\.css|\.sass|\.scss/; // alphabetized for future maintenance
```

This isn't fancy, but it is very clear and easy to add more later.

I tested it [here](https://regexr.com/) :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `\.([s]?[ac]ss)$` you match `.ass` because the leading `s` optional and the character class `[ac]` can match both characters.

Instead you could use lookarounds assertions, or use an alternation `|` to allow only certain alternatives.

Some other variations could be:

```
\.(s?c|sa)ss$
```

- `\.`Match a `.`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `s?c|sa` Match an optional `s` then match `c` or match `sa`
- `)` Close group 1
- `ss$` Match `ss` at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/duycpi/1)

```
\.(s[ac]|c)ss$
```

A variation on the previous pattern, now matching `sa` or `sc` or `c`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL6ixc/1)

If in your environment the lookbehind assertion is [supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind):

```
\.s?[ac]ss$(?<!\.ass)
```

- `\.s?` Match a `.` and optional `s`
- `[ac]` Match either `a` or `c`
- `ss$` Match `ss` at the end of the string
- `(?<!\.ass)` Negative lookbehind, assert not `.ass` to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9KpL75/1)

Note that if you want a match only, you can also use a non capture group `(?:...)` instead.