# Regex expression for "equal any of"

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, audience, tealium

I want to have a regex for if the variable value is equal to any of these values from the list.
[image]

I have a list of string values that contains some special characters like $ and -, for example

- Accident Only Hospital 750 - Basic
- Accident Only Hospital 500 - Basic
- Basic Accident Only Hospital $500 Excess
- Basic Accident Only Hospital $750 Excess
- Basic Hospital Cover with $250 Excess
- Basic Hospital Cover with $500 Excess
- BASIC HOSPITAL COVER
- Basic Plus Starter Hospital $500 Excess
- Basic Plus Starter Hospital $750 Excess
- Bronze Plus Simple Hospital $250 Excess
- Bronze Plus Simple Hospital $500 Excess
- Bronze Plus Simple Hospital $750 Excess
- Budget Family Hospital Cover with $250 Excess
- Budget Family Hospital Cover with $500 Excess
- Budget Family Hospital $750 Excess
- Budget Hospital with $500 Excess and Ambulance Levy
- Budget Hospital with $500 Excess
- Budget Hospital with $250 Excess and Ambulance Levy
- Budget Hospital with $250 Excess
- Budget Hospital with $1000 Excess and Ambulance Levy
- Budget Hospital with $1000 Excess
- Budget Hospital $750 Excess - Bronze Plus
- Established Family Hospital Cover with $250 Excess
- Established Family Hospital Cover with $500 Excess
- Established Family Hospital Cover with $750 Excess
- Gold Complete Hospital $500 Excess
- Gold Complete Hospital $750 Excess
- Growing Family Hospital Cover with $250 Excess
- Growing Family Hospital Cover with $500 Excess
- Prime Plus with Nil Excess Hospital
- Prime Plus with $250 Excess Hospital
- Prime Plus with $500 Excess Hospital
- Simple Start Hospital Cover
- Silver Plus Advanced Hospital $250 Excess
- Silver Plus Advanced Hospital $500 Excess
- Silver Plus Advanced Hospital $750 Excess
- Silver Plus Essential Hospital $250 Excess
- Silver Plus Essential Hospital $500 Excess
- Silver Plus Essential Hospital $500 Excess
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy - Gold
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy $250 Excess
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy $250 Excess - Gold
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy $500 Excess
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy $500 Excess - Gold
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy $750 Excess
- Top Hospital with Pregnancy $750 Excess - Gold
- Top Hospital Cover no Pregnancy
- Top Hospital Cover no Pregnancy with $250 Excess
- Top Hospital Cover no Pregnancy with $500 Excess

[image]
can someone please help me with that, i am not good with regex expressions, i have tried different expressions from google but no luck.

Comment: What is the variable? For regex, you can learn it here: https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex, take about 2-3h to pratice and you can do almost any regex you want

Comment: variable i mean any value that is part of the list, I am trying to build an audience as I have shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @Chicky I hope you understood the problem, can you please help me for now? it will be really appreciable, i am in kind of desperate need. I will for sure read the link that you have shared in the evening.

Comment: I'm willing to help but your question is not clear to me

Comment: I want to create audience based on "hospital product description" as shown in screenshot. If the "hospital product description" value is part of the given list. I have attached another screenshot of regex101 that might help you to understand the issue, please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: That regex works fine for me: https://regex101.com/r/XDYJCS/1

Comment: @NickODell thank you help but I don't think it is correct, it is only matching with first value in list, it is not matching the whole string which is present in testing string.

Comment: Try this if match whole string is what you need.
https://regex101.com/r/g5bCIH/1

Comment: Do you want string to be matched that contains special characters ?

Comment: [demo link](https://regex101.com/r/Wk6yKQ/1), see  if its fulfilling your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regular expression

```
^Top Hospital with Pregnancy[\w\W]*
```

Comment: I have updated the list, so this will not work, can you please have a look again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the string list pattern generator at [Optimize long lists of fixed string alternatives in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68275882/3832970):

```
^(?:(?:Accident Only Hospital (?:500 - Basic|750 - Basic)|B(?:asic (?:Accident Only Hospital \$(?:500 Excess|750 Excess)|Hospital Cover with \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess)|Plus Starter Hospital \$(?:500 Excess|750 Excess))|ASIC HOSPITAL COVER|ronze Plus Simple Hospital \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess|750 Excess)|udget (?:Family Hospital (?:Cover with \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess)|\$750 Excess)|Hospital (?:with \$(?:1000 Excess(?: and Ambulance Levy)?|250 Excess(?: and Ambulance Levy)?|500 Excess(?: and Ambulance Levy)?)|\$750 Excess - Bronze Plus)))|Established Family Hospital Cover with \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess|750 Excess)|G(?:old Complete Hospital \$(?:500 Excess|750 Excess)|rowing Family Hospital Cover with \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess))|Prime Plus with (?:Nil Excess Hospital|\$(?:250 Excess Hospital|500 Excess Hospital))|Si(?:mple Start Hospital Cover|lver Plus (?:Advanced Hospital \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess|750 Excess)|Essential Hospital \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess)))|Top Hospital (?:with Pregnancy(?: (?:- Gold|\$(?:250 Excess(?: - Gold)?|500 Excess(?: - Gold)?|750 Excess(?: - Gold)?)))?|Cover no Pregnancy(?: with \$(?:250 Excess|500 Excess))?)))$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5IraUi/1).